# Local DVD / CD Caches for SLES and OES2 Linux

Tags: linux, novell

I'd like to copy my SLES10SP3 and OES2SP2 disks to the system so I don't need to continually insert them for package management. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: With RHEL, I setup a local mirror for yum.  I suspect SLES has a similar solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly? Copy the ISO images to the server. Or better yet, set up an NFS host somewhere, localmount the ISO images, share out the mounted directories, and add those NFS exports as a repo.

```
mount -o loop /srv/iso/OES2-SP1-i386.iso /exports/OES2-SP1-i386
mount -o loop /srv/iso/SLES10-SP3-i586.iso /exports/SLES-10-SP3-i586
```

Then on your OES/SLES servers...

```
zypper sa server.with.nfs:/exports/OES2-SP1-i386/ "OES2 SP1 repo"
zypper sa server.with.nfs:/exports/SLES-10-sp3-i586/ "SLES-10-SP3 repo"
```

Or you can just copy the ISO files to each server, and then add the ISO as a Repository from YaST.

Comment: In fact to realistically do an in place upgrade from OES2 SP1 to SP2 it is best to have the SLES 10 SP3 DVD in the drive (or mounted via VMWare from the ISO, or via NFS) and then a copy of the ISO for OES 2 in the filesystem and mounted as above.

Comment: Yeah, I've done this before in RHEL, I didn't know if there was a "SUSE" way of doing things that was any different. Most of the documentation I perused in my initial (RTFM) moment seemed to be more about network based install, and not a locally cached source.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a local directory, stored the ISO's there. Went into repository management, chose "local directory" as my type and in the next dialog there is an option to choose an ISO as your source. This made this pretty painless. I've done repo changes before, just didn't know if there was a "SLES" or "Novell" way of doing things that works best. Thanks everyone.

Tom